subprocess.run() with capture_output=True
I am very new to Python.  I am trying to run some shell commands via Python's subprocess.run().  I would also like to capture the output of the shell commands.  When I run the command with capture_output=False, it seems to run fine.  But when I switch it to True, I get an error.
import subprocess

# runs just fine
subprocess.run("git --version", capture_output=False)

# throws error
subprocess.run("git --version", capture_output=True)
## OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid

After some further investigation, I think this is happening because I'm using Rstudio as my IDE.  When I try to run this in a Python shell, it works just fine.

capture_output=True sets stdout and stderr to subprocess.PIPE, meaning that standard output and error output are piped to the parent process. So yes it must have to do with the parent process being Rstudio. --I found a 5-year-old github thread discussing this exact issue, without any resolution.

The error occurs because subprocess.run() with capture_output=True does not work correctly with shell commands passed as a string. Instead, pass the command as a list:
import subprocess

# Correct way to capture output
result = subprocess.run(["git", "--version"], capture_output=True, text=True)

# Output
print(result.stdout)
#capture_output=True captures both stdout and stderr.
#text=True returns the output as a string instead of bytes.


What works depends on the OS. On Windows, the semantics are markedly different.

To run a shell command with subprocess, use the shell=True argument:
subprocess.run("git --version", shell=True, capture_output=True)

See the documentation (https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) for detailed information on how subprocess works.
The most relevant parts for your problems are:

args is required for all calls and should be a string, or a sequence
of program arguments. Providing a sequence of arguments is generally
preferred, as it allows the module to take care of any required
escaping and quoting of arguments (e.g. to permit spaces in file
names). If passing a single string, either shell must be True (see
below) or else the string must simply name the program to be executed
without specifying any arguments.

and

The shell argument (which defaults to False) specifies whether to use
the shell as the program to execute. If shell is True, it is
recommended to pass args as a string rather than as a sequence.

